# Google Analytics: Retrieve a list of all attributed touchpoints for a transaction?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-sdk

I am looking for way to export a touchpoint-based attribution from Google Analytics during a specific timeframe. I am not looking for sampled data, but something rather close to this:

```
|transaction_id|source|medium|campaign|click_id|attributed_value|
|1234          |google |cpc  |generics|<gcid>  |50%             |
|1234          |fb     |cpc  |campaign|<gcid>  |50%             |
```

I'd like to have all the touchpoints involved - along with their credit (wouldn't mind if its % or absolute value). Ideally, the used attribution model (linear, last click, first click...) would also be a parameter of such an export.

Is something close / similar to this possible?

Thanks a lot,
Alex